# What do employers think of Audited Courses?

Tags: resume, education

Afternoon all,

I'm curious if anyone has had any experience with employers and audited courses (i.e registered in a course, but not for credit). How do they perceive them? I'm faced with a scheduling decision regarding 4 courses. They're not my speciality, but they will provide me with a significant foundation of knowledge. And, further, will essentially allow me to meet the requirements of a second MSc.

I should add: I have the choice between auditing them, or doing them extra to my degree. Extra to the degree implies they appear on the transcript but don't factor into GPA. The problem I face is I would rather have an AU (audit) on my transcript than a low grade as the field is not my speciality. B seems like a minimum bound given the lectures so far but I won't know with any certainty until after the deadlines have passed.

Comment: Is the company paying for the course or is this a line-item on your CV?

Comment: Are you saying that the MSC gives credit for an audited course?

Comment: @ JeffO: it would be a line item. @ mhoran_psprep: no they do not; I don't actually need the degree it would just be nice to say I've met the requirements of the degree.

Comment: I would not say that having audited the course means you have met the requirements of a degree, until you have taken the course for a grade, you have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my perspective as senior professional, team lead and midlevel manager:

1. I don't care how you learned it, where you learned it, when you learned it and from whom you learned it. I care only that you know it.
2. If you know it and you have me trusting that you can make use of it, you know it so far as I am concerned. You have me trusting that you know it by telling me how you have made use of what you know. If you know it and you can't make use of it in a way that's relevant to our needs, then your knowing it is of no interest or consequence to me.
3. If you are dealing with a prospective employer, you are entitled to tell him "Show me the money!" a la Cuba Gooding Jr (*). On the other hand, your prospective employer might say "Show me your work!" :)

(*) I originally mistakenly attributed the quote to Ice Cube. My thanks to @tompedrz for the correction :)

Comment: I was hoping a someone in a position such as yours would provide some insight; the answer makes good sense.

Comment: #3 - Good point, wrong performer :-) It was Cuba Gooding Jr. in "Jerry Maguire" ...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaiSHcHM0PA

Comment: @tompedrz Thanks for the correction. I am editing my answer accordingly :)